# ImageProcessing in WPF (Fant BitmapScalingMode)

Tags: wpf, image-processing, image-manipulation

My application presents an image that can be scaled to a certain size. I'm using the Image WPF control with the scaling method of FANT.
However, there is no documentation how this scaling algorithm works.
Can anyone reference me to the relevant link for this algorithm description?

Nir

Answer (score 2):

Avery Lee of VirtualDub [states](http://www.virtualdub.org/blog/pivot/entry.php?id=300) that it's a box filter for downscaling and linear for upscaling. If I'm not mistaken, "box filter" here means basically that each output pixel is a "flat" average of several input pixels.

In practice, it's a lot more blurry for downscaling than GDI's cubic downscaling, so the theory about averaging sounds about right.

Answer (score -1):

I know what it is, but I couldn't find much on Google either :(

http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/freeabs_all.jsp?arnumber=4056711 is the appropriate paper I think; behind a pay-wall.

You don't need to understand the algorithm to use it.  You should explicitly make the choice each time you create a bitmap control that is scaled whether you want it high-quality scaled or low quality scaled.